# С чем связанны артефакты браузера?

Tags: kali-linux, wsl

Сегодня скачал kali linux на windows 10, попытался запустить firefox через консоль.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Вот что с ним происходит. Причём когда я двигаю окно, этот баг пропадает, но стоит мне остановить окно, снова появляется. Когда я запускаю kex и уже в нём запускаю firefox, то всё работает нормально.

Comment: У меня подобные артефакты появлялись перед тем, как видеокарта сдохла.